# Specify a start menu name abbreviation for ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, startmenu

I would like to specify an abbreviated Start Menu name for a click once application similar to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) or Microsoft Test Manager (MTM). The goal is to have the ability to hit Windows key + r, type the first letter of each word in the application name, and run (ex: type 'MCD' to launch 'Model Car Designer').

NOTE: I don't simply want to [change the Start Menu name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shfsy39d.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just boiled down to creating a new key in the registry.   [This blog post](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-open-any-program-by-typing-its-name-in-run-dialog-box-in-windows/) helped get me down the right path.

The new key I created had the same path as my application but I named the key the acronym ('MCD' in the question's example).